# Manipulating an API response to have part of the Object as a Key?

Tags: javascript

I have data that comes back from an API as an array of Objects.

```
const data = 
  [

      { 
        name: "Charles",
        age: 42, 
        height: 76
      },
      { 
        name: "Jim",
        age: 32, 
        height: 56
      },
      { 
        name: "Ed",
        age: 22, 
        height: 76
      }
  ]
```

rather than just returning that, `return data`, I'd like to have it where the name is the `key` so that I can do a lookup on `data`, like `data["Jim"]` and get the `object` back.

```
const data = 
      [
         {
          "Charles": 
             { 
               age: 42, 
               height: 76
            },
         },
         {
          "Jim": 
             { 
               age: 32, 
               height: 56
            },
         }
     ]
```

how can I manipulate the data to come back that way after getting it back from the API in the original format listed first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is this

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr.name]: {age: curr.age, height: curr.height}}), {});
```

now you can access like `result['Jim']`. You needed an object, not an array.